# Understanding the Template hierarchy

Tags: templates, template-hierarchy

I've got a template called `News`.

When I go to the Dashboard and edit the Page called `News` which has a web address of `news.html` I can see it uses this template (i.e. in the Page Attributes > Template section).

However, if I then update the Template Name (i.e. in `page-news.php`) to something like `NewsTest` and refresh the News Page in the Dashboard I see that WordPress has updated the Template being used in the Page Attributes > Template section.

Here's another more specific example:

If I then edit the slug to `newsaaa` and the template name to `Newsbbb` it still shows up in the Page Attributes > Template section.

I have been working my way through the [Template Hierarchy](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) but am still a bit puzzled how exactly WordPress knows which file it should use for that Page.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: As far as I know, WordPress doesn't connect the page with the template by the templates name but by the templates file name.

Comment: Please [improve your question title](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/writing-a-good-title). Summarize your specific problem, do not include the word WordPress.

Comment: @websupporter yes, you're right. that confused me initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look how page templates are saved against a page in the `wp_postmeta` table. Each page is linked to the specific template it uses and this is saved under the meta key `_wp_page_template`. You can go and have a look at your own install how you db structure looks like and how page templates are save

Wordpress does not use page slugs or page names but page id's to create the relationship to the page template assigned to it. Also, Wordpress does not use the template name to create the relationship to the page, but the page template file name. In the case of the default template, `page.php`, it is simply saved as `default` and not the file name

For that reason, you can rename the page slug and the template name to whatever you like and still have the relationship between the specific page and the template it uses.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The template name is defined **inside** the file, this way:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

This page will tell you all : https://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

Comment: Sebastien has the right idea, but doesn't explain why this is the answer. ... From what it sounds like you have a page-template called "News" (which the name is defined in the comment section, Sebastien points out, at the top of any page template file.) and the file name of this template is what you've been changing. WordPress uses the name in the comment section (see above) to display in the drop down when you are editing a page. So as you changed the file name, WP doesn't care and still had the News template selected because you didn't change the name in the drop down. Does that make sense?